# How to draw a filled oval on a graphics object?

Tags: java

How can I draw a filled oval of color red on a **Graphics** object created with **BufferedImage** which is filled with the color black? 
 
What I have tried:

```
public void draw(){
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(4, 5, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 4, 5);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(1, 1, 2, 2);
    g.dispose();
}
```

The result is a filled red rectangle in a filled black rectangle: 
[image]

But I want that filled red rectangle to be a filled red oval. How can I do that?

I want to use that image as a mouse cursor.

Comment: Maybe try it with a bigger image (Like 800*600) and bigger shapes. Maybe it's because you draw to small shapes, so an oval will render as a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a red rectangle because it is only 1 pixel tall and 2 pixels wide. Since there isn't enough space to simulate a curve, you won't get one. Try a bigger oval like `g.fillOval(100, 100, 200, 200);`